# Optimization with three variables

Tags: r, optimization, mathematical-optimization, linear-programming, constraint-programming

I have an equation with three variables to different ranges for the variables

```
f(x)= 150*x + 92*y + 41,1*z -> max
```

subject to

```
x > 0 & x < 600
x > 0 & x < 600
x+y+z <600
if x<200 or y<200 or x+y <200 -> z=0
```

I would like to find the maximum value for the variable. My knowledge of R is too small to be able to solve it by myself.

Comment: You may be looking for linear programming. Have a look at the [lpSolveAPI](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lpSolveAPI/index.html) package.

Comment: look at `constrOptim`. And provide real code.

Answer (score 1):

You could divide the problem in `z=0` and `z>=0`. For the second subproblem, you could set up and solve the problem like this:

```
library(lpSolveAPI)

# create object
lprec <- make.lp(0,3)
invisible(lp.control(lprec, sense="max")) # sense defaults to "min" 

# add objective and constraints
set.objfn(lprec, obj=c(150,92,41.1), indices=c(1,2,3)) 
add.constraint(lprec, 1, type="<=", rhs=600, indices=1)
add.constraint(lprec, 1, type=">=", rhs=200, indices=1)
add.constraint(lprec, 1, type="<=", rhs=600, indices=2)
add.constraint(lprec, 1, type=">=", rhs=200, indices=2)
add.constraint(lprec, c(1,1,1), type="<=", rhs=600, indices=c(1,2,3))
add.constraint(lprec, c(1,1), type=">=", rhs=200, indices=c(1,2))

# solve
print(lprec)
solve(lprec)
get.variables(lprec)
```

Note that I assumed that you meant `0<=y<=600` in your question. Note also that is not very useful (or possible) to set "<" constraints, it is much better to use "<=". At last, note that `lpSolveAPI` assumes non-negativity of the decision variables by default, hence it is assumed `z>=0`.

The first subproblem can be solved similarly. As you already know that in this case `z=0`, the number of decision variables reduces to `2`.

The solution to the problem is then the best of both subsolutions. As @RHertel already commented, it is the solution where you put as much as you can onto `x`, hence, `y` and `z` are 0.